# Can't set up GitHub Actions and Go

Tags: go, github-actions

I'm getting the following error when trying to build Go project with GitHub Actions. Can't figure out why as the project is literally empty. `go build` works fine locally.

```
Run go build -v ./...
go: errors parsing go.mod:
/home/runner/work/goActionsTest/goActionsTest/go.mod:1: unknown directive: version
/home/runner/work/goActionsTest/goActionsTest/go.mod:2: unknown directive: oid
/home/runner/work/goActionsTest/goActionsTest/go.mod:3: unknown directive: size
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

```yaml
# This workflow will build a golang project
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-go

name: Go

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up Go
      uses: actions/setup-go@v4
      with:
        go-version: '1.20'

    - name: Build
      run: go build -v ./...
```

`go.mod`:

```
module test

go 1.20
```

My project structure:

[image: Project structure]

I tried the code from [a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrOyxUBILF8). Literally I copied all [the code](https://github.com/thomaslanghorst/github-actions-golang) to a new repository and I'm getting exactly the same errors.

Comment: Use a proper module name. Try building locally first.

Comment: Locally `go build` works and generates correct executable. What's proper module name? I tried using github URI instead of `test` and it didn't work.

Comment: Replacing `./...` with `.` seems to fix things.